Legend or not: wood coat should "breath"?
I am going to stain some pine boards, then coat them with boiled linseed oil. The latter should let moisture to diffuse through (correct me if I am wrong), but the water-based stain produces poorly permeating barrier (according to the manufacturer). The humidity will change maybe from 20-80%, and the wood could sometimes be exposed to little sprinkles of water (in indoors however). Is it just a legend that wood should "breathe" even in these somewhat mild conditions? What could happen if I would fully coat the wood with the stain, and then use the boiled linseed oil on top of it, chipping, mould spots? Or should I leave some parts open from the stain to let the moisture in the wood equalize with the surroundings through the boiled linseed oil coat?

Unless you are trying to paint over wet wood, I don't see a problem. Note that the stain or the oil-based coating will not adhere to the damp surface.

I think you're over-worrying about this, unless you live in like Indonesia and there are local methods that get used there.  I doubt a single engineer in the last 100 years has taken a class in wood surface prep, ask on a carpentry forum.

You need to specify the species and dimensions, the stain type, and the environmental conditions. I suggest starting with a drying oil like a modified tung oil and see if that works for you. I recommend food grade for interior surfaces. You can pigment tung oil with paint pigments or oil based stains. You can apply tung oil over water-based stains. This worked pretty good for 30 years on my sailboat's wooden interior. In warmer conditions, a good, breathable, anti mold finish is the best protection for the wood and easy and safe for people. I use BLO on cedar shingle roofs and not much else.

Thanks @tigerguy and everybody else as well. I wasn't aware of the wood working under stack exchange, just noticed it. Yeah, I wouldn't even think about the issue unless recommended by another handyman.
